# How to implement Activity indicator to render until flat list data is displayed? React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, hook, use-state, activity-indicator

I have a flat list with some hardcoded data. How can I implement the Activity indicator to spin and to be displayed until the flat list data is completely displayed on the screen? Below is my code. Thanks

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

import { MainScreenCard } from '../mainScreen.components/mainScreen.card';
import { Spacer } from '../assets.driveAround/spacer';

export const MainScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  
  return(
    <>
  <FlatList
      data={[
        { name: 1 },
        { name: 2 },
        { name: 3 },
        { name: 4 }
      ]}
      renderItem={() => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}>
        <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
          <MainScreenCard/>
        </Spacer>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
      contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 16 }}
    />
    </>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main options depending on how you want to refresh. If you want to pull from the top of the screen to refresh provide it a refresh control
https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol

```
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={refreshing}
            onRefresh={onRefresh}
          />
        }
      >
        <Text>Pull down to see RefreshControl indicator</Text>
      </ScrollView>
```

Otherwise, another simple option is to use an ActivityIndicator to show a spinner overtop of the view
https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

...

<ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" animating={loading}/>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. However I am not sure pull to refresh is working inside the flat list. I implemented the example code and nothing is happening. Can you please provide specific example of  <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" animating={loading}/> how can I implement in code above? how do I setLoading? Thanks

Comment: Check out the React Native doc link for a better example of it in a view, but it's just a simple component that you place in your JSX. And replace loading with whatever variable you would be using to keep track of whether or not the spinner should be showing. If you're logging in to something call setLoading at the beginning of that

Comment: for some reason my activity indictor is not showing in the flatlist while i fetch data, only when pulling it shows it. if i use your second option it messes with my unit test because the view isn t loaded u yet.